# @ExceptionHandler not getting called on exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, soap

I'm migrating a SOAP service to REST. What I do is I have an wsdl definition, and I use that to automatically generate the request and response classes with JAXB.

This is my endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class RefundServiceEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private RefundService refundService;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = RefundException.class)
    public void handleException(RefundException exception) {
        // This should be called
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = UnableToMapException.class)
    public void handleException(UnableToMapException exception) {
    // This should be called

    }

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest serverRequest;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ReturnRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ReturnResponse returnRequest(@RequestPayload ReturnRequest request) {
        return this.refundService.partialRefund(request, serverRequest).getBody();
    }
}
```

I'm throwing those two exceptions but the handlers don't get called.
The only way I managed to get them is with a try/catch but I'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks

Comment: That isn't a controller it isn an endpiont...

Comment: To clarify what @M.Deinum is saying: `@ExceptionHandler` works at `@Controller` level, but this isn't a `@Controller`. What's wrong with try/catch?